# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen de internet en un JPanel?

Tags: java, jframe, imagen

Mi intención es mostrar en un JPanel una imagen almacenada en Internet pasándole la URL.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que hayas intentado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres pasar mediante una URL tendrías que hacer lo siguiente para obtener la imagen utilizando un JLabel que te podría convenir más:

Importando los siguientes componentes:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
```

Obtenemos la imagen pasando la URL:

```
Image image = null;
URL url = new URL("http://www.sitio.com/path/imagen.png");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Luego si quieres mostrar en un elemento de Swing que te permita mostrarlo podrías hacerlo con:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
frame.add(label);
```

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Justo lo que buscaba.